# Css transform flip flipping back and IE issue

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to do a css card flip effect and am having a few issues here. Firstly - I cannot seem to get the javascript to get the card flip to revert the flip. I have a call for a click on either face, and for some reason it is not firing on the back side of the card.

Secondly, I cannot seem to get this animation to work in ie10-11. The card simply flips one way and disappears. I tried a few techniques but couldn't seem to figuire it out.

Here's what I'm working on -  http://jsfiddle.net/4j9fv61L/5/

Lastly, when I put content on the card it seems to flicker when it moves, and if it's an image on the front it seems to still show up when I flip it onto it's backside (in chrome). I tried adding -

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden
backface-visibility: hidden
```

to a few things as recommended for the flickering, but it didn't seem to entirely fix the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am new to css animations. Thanks for reading!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you can't click on the `.flipMe` element as it's facing the other way. You can get around this by not transforming that element, but transforming the `.front` and `.back` elements instead.

Firstly, remove the `transition` from `.flipMe` and add that to your `.front` and `.back` elements. Then change:

```css
.flipMe {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

To:

```css
.flipMe .front {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flipMe .back {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
```

With this your `.flipMe` element never rotates, and thus the click still applies regardless of how the `.front` and `.back` are rotated.

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/4j9fv61L/6/).

This also seems to fix the IE issue you've described as well, which is a bonus!